# Material Ui Components props refer each other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reference, event-handling, material-ui

How do I make material UI component property to carry the value of some other property of same component?
Here I want value property to refer checked property.
want to do something like this

```
    <Switch
                checked={singleHeading.required}
                onChange={onHandleChangeCheck}
                name="required"
                value={event.target.checked}
              />
```

Comment: What about using the same variable `singleHeading.required` for both props (`checked` and `value`) ?

Comment: singleHeading.required assigns the initial value of checked...When its switched event.target.checked changes from true to false or from false to true while singleHeading.required remains same unless changed in onChange function otherwise...So i want to use that changed value of checked in value...Thats possible with referencing only

Comment: You can use the `useState` hook to perform that if the value is not store in your global state. I'll add a code snippet as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using hooks you can perform that with this:

```
render() {
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(singleHeading.required);
    const handleSwitchCheck = event => {
        setChecked(event.target.checked);
        onHandleChangeCheck(event);
    };

    // ... whatever code you have

    <Switch
            checked={checked}
            onChange={handleSwitchCheck}
            name="required"
            value={checked}
          />

    // ... whatever code you have
}
```